How to compute catalytic efficiency from O2 readings?
The Torque App does not seem to have this functionality. Is there other software that does? If not, assuming that I can get the readings into a CSV or other file, is there a well-accepted formula or algorithm for doing so?

Efficiency measured in what terms?

Actually, not sure. There is an OBD2 code for efficiency, so basically something akin to what it measures. I sometimes get the code, then it goes away for months, so curious about how it was being computed. I understand the closed-loop control will cause the upstream to fluctuate. The downstream then should be relatively stable, but I don't know the exact computation.

In order to calculate this you need to manually move fueling around and monitor the o2 sensors, in majority of ecu’s this is nothing you can command manually.  The ecu’s do this themselves while cruising, you can see micro movements of lambda set points.  The result is stored in RAM, and used to compare against thresholds, outside of them you get those P0420 and P0430 codes.  None of this is something you can regularly see through standard obd pid’s, you’d need advanced RAM logging and ability to flash the ECU to truly understand how it computes.
